# How can I detect a word in a sentence from a list?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm creating a discord bot, in which I want it to delete messages whenever someone sends a message and it contains a specific word, in this case, a bad word.

```
f = open("filter_words.txt", 'r')
list = f.read()
f.close()

msg = message.content
msg = msg.lower()

if msg in list:
    await message.delete()
    await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}'s message was deleted")
```

`filter_words.txt` contains a list of bad words `{'word', 'another'}`. Here the code only deletes the message if someone types only the word. I want it to delete the message if the word is anywhere in the sentence. I hope I explained this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```py
def check_bad_word(msg, list):
    ''' Detect bad word.'''
    # Loop over all bad word
    for word in list:
        # bad word found ('in' can make wrong detection)
        if word in msg:
             return True
    return False

if check_bad_word(msg, list)
    await message.delete()
    await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}'s message was deleted")
```

Comment: Well now, bot del almost anything ;-;

Comment: it separate all the words into letters, so it dels whatever letter is in the list of bad words

Answer (score 1):

Split message.content and then check each word in filtered words list (considering filtered words are more than words in message)

```
with open("filter_words.txt", 'r') as f:
    filtered_words = f.read()
msg = message.content
msg = msg.lower()
msg_list = msg.split()

for word in msg_list:
    if word in filtered_words:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}'s message was deleted")
        break
```

Comment: Add break in loop. Not need check other bad words after deleting message.

Comment: yes. thanks, @СергейЗайков. editing answer

Comment: I don't know why I am still facing a problem, it seems to break down the words in msg to a single letter.
for example "Word" is in the list of bad words, so when I type "w" it del the msg same for all other letters in the word. it happens even if the letter is in a different sentence like with.

Comment: keep list of bad word in filter_words using some delimeter (space or newline)

Comment: `it seems to break down the words in msg to a single letter`. No, this should not happen. share filter_words data and message data. will be clear to understand @FunkySplash48